# Proof of existence in balls

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hello guys I have a problem with proving the following ...

> Given x $\in S[a;r]$ y $ \epsilon > 0$ prove that it exists y $\in B(a;r)$ and z $\not\in B[a;r]$ such that $||y-x||<\epsilon$ and $||z-x||<\epsilon$

I was able to prove that "y" is in the open ball said by writing it as a function of "a" and "x" since the ball is convex it can be written by a t between [0,1] as you already know and playing with the inequalities i was able to find that t should be taken to have the proper y given the epsilon but i tried to use the same argument with z which is outside the ball but i didn't achieve anything, any clue how i can achieve it?

Comment: The set of points of the form $(1-t)a+tx$, with $t \color{red}{\in \Bbb R}$, is precisely the line through $a$ and $x$. Find suitable values for $t$ to find $y$ and $z$.